# Google VR for unity:FPS is low when i open the vr mode

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr

I'm using GoogleVR for unity to develop a virtual reality application.

When I run the app on a Nexus 5, I find that the FPS is very low, about 18-20. Then, when I close the VR mode and run it again, the fps is back to 60.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Your question is too abroad, it is better if you show us some details or being specific, maybe you need to find the culprit or atleast show something usefull.

Comment: Try changing the V Sync Count to Don't Sync in Quality settings.

Comment: @郭绍宏 ever find a solution? Having a nightmare time trying to get FPS to 60+.

Comment: i can only reduce the screen`s resolution to Increase FPS~。~